# Using Geopandas on python to create an interactive map

Tags: python, dictionary, geopandas

I'm trying to create an interactive map using this guide: [This](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-complete-guide-to-an-interactive-geographical-map-using-python-f4c5197e23e0)

I use pycharm with anaconda environment, so I don't understand when put my .shp file. This is the example code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
shapefile = 'data/countries_110m/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp'
#Read shapefile using Geopandas
gdf = gpd.read_file(shapefile)[['ADMIN', 'ADM0_A3', 'geometry']]
```

Is this correct my directory?

```
C:\Users\gpont\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\data\Map\map1\ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\gpont\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject2\python.exe C:/Users/gpont/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fiona/_shim.pyx", line 83, in fiona._shim.gdal_open_vector
  File "fiona/_err.pyx", line 270, in fiona._err.exc_wrap_pointer
fiona._err.CPLE_OpenFailedError: 'map1 e_110m_admin_0_countries.shp' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gpont/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    gdf = gpd.read_file(shapefile)[['ADMIN', 'ADM0_A3', 'geometry']]
  File "C:\Users\gpont\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject2\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py", line 96, in _read_file
    with reader(path_or_bytes, **kwargs) as features:
  File "C:\Users\gpont\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject2\lib\site-packages\fiona\env.py", line 398, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gpont\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject2\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py", line 253, in open
    c = Collection(path, mode, driver=driver, encoding=encoding,
  File "C:\Users\gpont\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject2\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.session.start(self, **kwargs)
  File "fiona/ogrext.pyx", line 484, in fiona.ogrext.Session.start
  File "fiona/_shim.pyx", line 90, in fiona._shim.gdal_open_vector
fiona.errors.DriverError: 'map1 e_110m_admin_0_countries.shp' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thank you in advance.

Giovanni

Comment: If I use this:

```import geopandas as gpd

# Read shapefile using Geopandas
gdf = (gpd.read_file(r"C:\Users\gpont\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\data\Map\map1\ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp"))[['ADMIN', 'ADM0_A3', 'geometry']]

# Rename columns
gdf.columns = ['country', 'country_code', 'geometry']
gdf.head()
```

I don't receive any output, only: Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a `\n` in your path, which is interpreted as a newline character. (Note the missing `n` in `'map1 e_110m_admin_0_countries.shp' does not exist`)

Try

```
import os
...
gpd.read_file(os.path.normpath(shapefile))
```